# c# Which situation people go for singleton design pattern

Tags: c#

here is a sample of singleton design pattern code. i just new few scenario when people design singleton class.....please mention few scenario.

i often saw people develop logger with singleton design pattern approach but why it is required because we can develop a logger without singleton design pattern.

if anyone knows real reason please share with me. thanks

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton()
    {
    }

    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    private static Singleton instance = null;
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Singleton();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just extra info for novice readers: the implementation above is one example of a thread-safe singleton pattern.

Comment: There are different ways of doing anything. You never need to use the singleton pattern, but some people choose to.

Comment: I would personally say it was because you only want one instance of the logger, but once again there is no specific reason why a singleton above anything else

Comment: We have some lookup tables defined in a database. They change only rarely, and there's a little bit of overhead when the application goes to the webservice and the webservice queries the database. So we load these as singleton collections, and an option to refresh all of them on demand. As noted, there are other ways to do the same thing, but that's one real-world use case of a singleton.

Comment: it means there is no scenario where people has to go for singleton pattern? am i right?

Comment: @Tridip In a job interview, sometimes they'll ask you to write an example of a singleton. Sometimes, your manager at work will tell you to write one. In both cases, your best option is probably to write a singleton. But do as you like.

Comment: No one has mentioned that classes that use the singleton pattern are generally horrible for unit testing, but they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the needs of the application as to whether or not a singleton is needed. Generally you'd like to avoid using the pattern as there are usually instance-level ways of doing things like sharing data across threads, etc. though doing so may involve writing more complex code.

One example would be to cache database look-ups across processes. Any implementation is specific to the needs application, though it may not necessarily be *required*, i.e., as there usually other ways of achieving the same aim.

There is a better explanation of the whys on the software engineering site of SE [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/384/285377).

Answer (score 0):

Singleton makes since when the object is expensive to construct, but in most application architectures today there isn't a lot of room for the singleton pattern as described in the Gang of Four book.  The "classic" implementation of a singleton as you described makes use of static methods, which in turn become a major dependency magnet and make it more difficult to accomplish IoC.  I can't think of a case today where I would use an object specifically coded as a singleton rather than pass an object that *happens* to be the only one constructed.

The way that I would today achieve the *goal* represented by the Singleton pattern would be to configure my IoC container to create only a single instance of that particular type when resolving dependencies.